# How to use "forbear" as an imperative

Tags: word-usage

According to [freedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/forbear), the verb *forbear* is often followed by *from* or an infinitive.

I ran a [search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forbear%20from%20thinking%2Cforbear%20to%20think%2Cforbear%20thinking&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforbear%20from%20thinking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforbear%20to%20think%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforbear%20thinking%3B%2Cc0) on ngram with the specific example I need (with the verb *think*) and found out that the most used version is actually the one that uses a gerund (without *from*).

I have two questions:

**1. Can I even use the verb *forbear* as an imperative?**

I know that I could use *refrain* or *hold back*, but I need to sound archaic.

For instance:

> Forbear desiring your neighbour's wife.

**2. Which of the three options is the most appropriate for an imperative?**

> - Forbear desiring your neighbour's wife.
> - Forbear from desiring your neighbour's wife.
> - Forbear to desire your neighbour's wife.

Comment: We don't use the word **forbear** in everyday speech, it is becoming archaic.

Comment: Thanks @weatherVane, I know. But, as I wrote, I need to sound archaic.

Comment: It's an unusual usage too. You can't **forbear** or **refrain** from a desire - you either desire something, or you don't.

Comment: I agree with @weathervane - the forebearance would be on ACTING out the desire, not on having it in the first place. Of your three, "forbear from" sounds most accurate,, but I might try to find a way to insert some notion of acting upon the desire rather than just having it. If giving up that desire, then forsaking would seem a better word.

Comment: Yes, for example "forbear from succumbing to desire for your neighbour's wife."

Comment: I don't agree that 'forbear' is archaic, except perhaps to Generation Z. I will allow that it may be considered slightly old-fashioned by others, but it is still a good, useful word.

Comment: “*Thou shalt not covet*” doesn’t sound archaic?

Comment: *Desire not thy neighbor's wife.*

Comment: What about your neighbour/neighbor's ass?

Comment: I have to say, as a Briton, and that is important, that my neighbour has a very nice ass.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Neither do I see why "forbear" should be regarded as "archaic" - but if it is so what? I am rather fond of the archaic. The OED lists 9 senses of the verb, most of which are declared "obsolete" or "rare". Some are not. But as far as I'm concerned, a derivation such as "forbearance" is very much part of everyday speech. If the verb "forbear" is "archaic", let us all endeavour to breathe life into it. Recent English has become numb enough with simplicity.

Comment: Some senses of the verb take the preposition "from", others do not. But those that do can form the imperative simply by saying something like: *Forbear from breathing a word of this matter to anyone.*

Answer (score 2):

The definitive English usage of *forbear* is surely [the epitaph on Shakespeare’s grave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitaph#Notable_examples):

[image: epitaph on shakespeare's grave]
<sup>William Shakespeare's grave, Holy Trinity Church, Stratford-on-Avon, England.
<sup>**ᴀᴛᴛʀɪʙᴜᴛɪᴏɴ**: Clipping of [image by David Jones from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Shakespeare_grave_-Stratford-upon-Avon_-3June2007.jpg)</sup></sup>

Containing this quatrain in [iambic tetrameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_tetrameter):

> Good frend for Iesvs sake forebeare,
>   To digg the dvst encloased heare.
>   Bleste be þͤ man þͭ spares thes stones,
>   And cvrst be he þͭ moves my bones.

Which in modern spelling reads:

> > *Good friend for Jesus’ sake forbear,
> >
> >     To dig the dust enclosed here.
> >
> >     Blest be the man that spares these stones,
> >
> >     And cursed be he that moves my bones.*

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, and as you wish to be "archaic", the verb to forbear + from (intransitive and reflexive) is agood choice:

Yes, there is no reason why you should not use "forbear" in the imperative.

OED:

> 7. a. transitive. To refrain from using, uttering, mentioning, etc.; to withhold, keep back. **†Formerly const. from, to, or dative.**
>
> b. reflexive. To restrain oneself, refrain. rare.
>
> 1611   Bible (King James) 2 Chron. xxxv. 21   Forbeare thee from medling with God.

Thus "Forbear thee/theyself from desiring your neighbour's wife." would be good 16th century English and be so archaic as to be obsolete.

My only caveat is that your examples look like attempts at changing a Bible verse: Exodus 20:17b. The verse in the 1611 King James Version is

> 17 ... thou shalt not couet thy neighbours wife,

and that is genuinely archaic.